# Different Entitlements.plist files in terms of receiving push notifications

Tags: ios, push-notification, provisioning, entitlements, code-signing-entitlements

I have a setup where my app code is compiled to two different targets. One is the Staging and one is the Production.

Both can receive push-notifications, for this there are different certificates, provisioning files etc. (and info.plist files as well).

My problem is that push notifications registers, prompts the user and shows up in the iOS setting for only one of the apps.

It seems there is some setting that is either shared or not shared correctly between the two apps.

I found this in the Push Notification documentation:

> When you create a provisioning profile for one of the environments, the requisite entitlements are automatically added to the profile, including the entitlement specific to push notifications, . The two provisioning profiles are called Development and Distribution. The Distribution provisioning profile is a requirement for submitting your application to the App Store.

I my case I have two production environments. I have only one entitlements.plist file and as I read the above there must be one for each Push Certificate.

If I look in my entitlements file it does not mention anything about push etc. Only the "can be debugged" element. Is Apple referring to a different entitlements file?

If two entitlements is what I need, how do I generate them to adhere to the provisioning profile used in a specific target?